# Should I fast-forward a branch after merged to a different branch

Tags: git

Given that I have two branches `dev` and `master`

I do most of development on `dev` and then make a merge to `master` with `--no-ff`.

Because I used `--no-ff`, there is a new commit created on `master` (Let's call this commit A).

Should I fast-forward commit A onto my `dev` branch before I continue to develop on `dev`?

Is there any benefit of bringing commit A onto my `dev`? Would it be an anti-pattern to bring this commit A onto `dev` branch?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why branch? Why not fast forward?

Comment: @jonrsharpe One reason could be that github does not offer a fast forward merge option in pull requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is neither any real cost, nor any real benefit.

Remember that *branch names* are largely [ephemeral](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ephemeral), and in any case certainly evolve over time.  If you keep both names around for a long time—the one named `master`, you'll probably keep—then at some time in the future, you would see this pattern of commits:

```
(time increasing towards the right)

o--o---------M-----N   <-- master
    \       /     /
     o--o--o--o--o   <-- dev
```

for the first case, where you `git merge --no-ff` `dev` into `master` to create merge `M` at some time T, and then `git merge` again to create merge `N` at some later time.

[(OP notes that this first pattern might be something desirable in a release branch, e.g., one named `production` where the name on the lower row is `master`.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657893/should-i-fast-forward-a-branch-after-merged-to-a-different-branch/56657987?noredirect=1#comment99886892_56657987)

If you allow `dev` to rejoin `master` at `M`, you will instead get:

```
o--o---------M------N   <-- master
    \       / \    /
     o--o--o   o--o   <-- dev
```

Is this better?  Is it worse?  Will you care?

If you *take away* the `dev` name, and instead use `feature` names, you might see:

```
o--o---------M------N   <-- master
    \       / \    /
     o--o--o   o--o
```

where the first bubble along the bottom row was temporary name `feature/foo` and the second bubble was temporary name `feature/zorg`.

Again, the real question will be: do you care?  The only things that are permanent here are the commits themselves.  Make the commit messages good—the default `merge ...` messages are kind of terrible, but at least something like:

```
merge branch feature/foo
```

and:

```
merge branch feature/zorg
```

offer *some* clue as to what this was about.  Compare with:

```
merge branch dev
```

which tells you nothing at all, regardless of which stitch pattern you observe in the commits.

Comment: Your explanation make me realized that my question is quite arbitrary and it all depends on the purpose of the branch. For your 1st case, may be it make sense to call the branches `production` and `master` instead of `master` and `dev` respectively. And for your 2nd case, it make sense to call `master` and have the `feature` branches rejoin `master` after the merge. If you can update your answer to reflect the idea, it may help other people when they see this question. Thanks,

Comment: @LxL: I put a note in, but I'll add that in actual release management as I've seen it, one winds up with multiple active release branches (for ongoing support of version 5 while version 6 is being sold, for instance) and it gets pretty messy.

Comment: "Will you care?" <- I just encountered a scenario where I do. I am using a versioning tool that creates version numbers from the latest tag, something similar to `<tag_name>+<n commits>#<sha>`. After merging `dev` into `master` I want both branches to identify as the same version (because both branches are deployed to different environments). Therefore I fast-forward `dev` after the merge.

Comment: @timgeb: Interesting: your CI system reads the commit messages. (Does it have any protection against users faking them? Not that it necessarily *needs* any such protection, but it seems a bit weird to scavenge for the default messages, which will backfire when someone puts in a better message instead. :-) So then someone who wants to put in a better message should keep the default message too, perhaps.)

Comment: Not sure I follow. Nothing is read from the commit messages, but from the tag (created with `git tag -a ...`). Anyway the setup has some details I did not explain to keep it short. Just wanted to to mention that I had a real life situation where I cared where `dev` pointed to after the merge.

Comment: @timgeb: Ah, I misread. But yes, as soon as you find a reason to care, you will care :-)